# Using ads with phone gap

Tags: jquery, cordova, mobile, ads

I've been working on an app that I've built using JqueryMobile and Phonegap. Does anyone know what the best way to show ads in your app when you're using Phonegap. Can I use adMob or Google ads or what should I use.

Thanks  /Johannes

Comment: Have a look at this link : http://www.adploits.com/2011/10/05/jquery-mobile-and-google-adsense-working/

Answer (score 1):

I don't the best way of integrating ads ......but google ads works pretty good with phonegap applications.
I personally have used google ads in phonegap application.